# How to get Rails Admin date filters to follow the Rails app's timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a Rails app and use [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) for back-office. I have my app's timezone set to 'Melbourne' but its Date filters only show results in UTC. How can I change this behaviour to follow the app's timezone?

I have looked into [this](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2289) issue, [this](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1727) issue and [this](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1545) issue but can't seem to find a way to change filters such as 'today' to work with the app's timezone.

I have set the app's timezone on `application.rb` - `config.time_zone = 'Melbourne'`. The Datetime columns look fine on Rails Admin (it shows Melbourne time on `created_at` and `updated_at`) but filters such as 'today' only show results in UTC.

This causes the Date filters to only be correct after 0000 UTC, which causes the team to retrieve the wrong information from the platform. Any tips on how to sort this out would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can try:

STEP 1:

IN `rails_admin.rb` file

```
require 'rails_admin/config/fields/base'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Fields
      module Types
        class Datetime < RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Base
          def value
            value_in_default_time_zone = bindings[:object].send(name)
            return nil if value_in_default_time_zone.nil?
            pacific_time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('YOUR_TIMEZONE')
            value_in_default_time_zone.in_time_zone(pacific_time_zone)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

STEP 2:

IN `config/envirements/production.rb`

add two rows

```
config.time_zone = 'YOUR_TIMEZONE'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'YOUR_TIMEZONE'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I tried this code and the variations that I found the issues linked in my question and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the post from MaxMartiFoundry [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2289#issuecomment-553559820), I was finally able to fix the date filters on my Rails Admin.

I updated MaxMartiFoundry's suggestion and added the following code to a file on `<root>/lib/rails_admin.rb`:

```
module RailsAdmin
  AbstractModel::StatementBuilder::FilteringDuration.class_eval do
    def today
      [Time.current, Time.current]
    end

    def yesterday
      [Time.current.yesterday, Time.current.yesterday]
    end

    def this_week
      [Time.current.beginning_of_week, Time.current.end_of_week]
    end

    def last_week
      [Time.current.beginning_of_week - 1.week, Time.current.end_of_week - 1.week]
    end
  end
end
```

It's working for me so I hope this helps someone else!